# Can we recover a deleted page from FitNesse via revision tab?

Tags: fitnesse

I moved one of the FitNesse Page to another one. I found that I moved it to the wrong place. I went to that wrong path and deleted that page. As I moved the original page, I am not able to locate that.

Can anybody has any idea of recovering a deleted page?

Comment: this is why it's a good idea to store your fitnesse tests in version control.

Answer (score 1):

Pages in the Fitnesse wiki are stored as text files directly in the filesystem - deleting a page deletes the file (doesn't go to recycle bin or anything).

So there's no way to recover the file unless you're using a source control system.

(Or if the wiki is on a server, say, and nightly backups are taken, you could recover the file from the nightly backup, perhaps).

Answer (score 1):

we can restore deleted contet of wiki page with a tool called Recuva...it is amazing tool...